# Cannot get text to stay appended inside div after button press

Tags: html, button, append

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Library Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="practice.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
      <h1>Library</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="bottomContainer">

      <div class="button">
        <button id="newBook" onclick="displayCard();">New Book</button>
      </div>

      <div class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="window">
          <form action="">
            <div class="close-btn">
              <p>Add A New Book</p>
              <button class="x">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title" value="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Author" id="author" value="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pages" id="pages" value="">
            <button class="submit" onclick="createDiv();">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cards"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

```js
// Button Stuff //
let newBook = document.getElementById("newBook");
let cardsContainer = document.querySelector(".cardsContainer");
let x = document.querySelector(".x");

// Brings up & closes form window //
function displayCard() {
  cardsContainer.style.display = "flex";
}

//  Creates Div  //
function createDiv() {
  alert("working");
  let cards = document.querySelector(".cards");
  let strong = document.createElement("strong");

  strong.textContent = "strong";
  cards.append(strong);

};
```

I have two buttons. The first button brings up a modal that has a "Submit" button on it. When I press "Submit" I want to add the word "Strong" to the div ".cards". The button alerts "working" and then strong appears on the screen but when I click off the alert, the word "strong" disappears. I tried changing the code around so that when I press the "New Book" button the word strong appears and stays, however, if I try to also have the modal come up after, the word "strong" disappears again. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I just need to be able to append stuff after hitting the "Submit" button.

Comment: Your button is a submit, which means if you do not stop the submit action, after your function is executed the page submits (to itself) and effectly reloads, which would reset the **strong** you added. You can either change the submit to a regular button, or if it **must** remain a submit, you will need to add the function as an event listener so that you can capture the event object and use `preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: I'm at work but I'll try when I get home. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I checked the code again and my Submit button has a class called submit but isn't type of Submit

Comment: Do you need the `<form>`, because copying your code the result I got was definitely a form submit. Again the simplest fix should be `<input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="createDiv();">`, but if for some reason the form still submits you need to use `preventDefault()`, which will mean the function needs to be assigned as an event listener (so you can capture the event object when the function runs).

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that form refreshed the page like that.